# How to parse ">" which is not tag

Tags: r, xml

I want write XML file, whose main main task is to keep metadata and key words about various attacks.

```
<attack id="1">
    <date>2018-01-12</date>
    <name>xss attack</name>
    <group>injection</group>
    <description>find xss attack</description>
    <allkeywords>  
        <keyword>  
            "<"
         </keyword>
         <keyword>  
            "</"
         </keyword>  
     </allkeywords>  
</attack>
```

Problem is that keywords are opening and ending tags in XML. So when I try parse this type of XML in R.

```
require(XML)
data_xml <- xmlTreeParse("C:\\data\\attacks.txt")
```

It gives this error:

> Opening and ending tag mismatch.

How to solve it? What is the right way how to write  ">", which is not XML tag to XML file?

Comment: Maybe using [escaping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML) does help? Or using [CDATA sections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA#Uses_of_CDATA_sections)?